# filereader API in Meteor how to read as binary string

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, filereader

I am trying to read the contents of a file (any format but testing with a hello.txt with contents= 'hello') and output the binary string to the console in Meteor, I'm new to the framework. Whenever I check the console there is a new entry of 'undefined'. What am I missing here?

HTML

```
<div>
Select a file: 
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
</div>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    window.onload = function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      // Put the rest of the demo code here.
      var file = fileInput.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
      var rawData = reader.result;
      }

      var output = reader.readAsBinaryString(file); 
      console.log(output);

});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work, the data will be available inside the `reader.onload` method, So here the data is in `rawData` variable and move your `console.log()` code to the `reader.onload` function

JS:

```
 if (Meteor.isClient) {

window.onload = function() {
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // Put the rest of the demo code here.
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
   var rawData = reader.result;
   console.log(rawData);
  }

  var output = reader.readAsBinaryString(file); 


  });
 }
}
```